# installing php-gd dependencies on alpine linux in php5-fpm-alpine docker container

Tags: docker

Trying to install GD dependencies on alpine linux in docker.

I'm building php5-fpm-alpine image.

```
FROM php:5-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apk upgrade --update && apk add \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libfreetype6-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libfreetype6-dev]
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libjpeg62-turbo-dev]
  libpng12-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libpng12-dev]
```

I've limited experience with alpine distro. and it seems to be not very popular, ergo little information or not at all via google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package names in the example from docker hub are for the debian version. You must use the packages from alpine. You can search for alpine packages here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages.

The following should work:

```
FROM php:5-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apk upgrade --update && apk add \
  coreutils \
  freetype-dev \
  libjpeg-turbo-dev \
  libltdl \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libpng-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Comment: yes I realised that, but I couldn't find relevant packages... where do I read up php-gd what dependencies it needs and what are package names for various distros?

Comment: Here for example, on the right side, dependencies: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86_64/php-gd

Comment: so in your code we have 1 extra coreutils this is not listed as php-gd dependency. why did you include it?

Comment: I've got this error on configure step: `Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.`  And it's because all building packages are purged..

Comment: Why would you need the `coreutils` package?